# Update and Add tags post on save post using wp_update_post

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I'm trying to build a function to use in saving the post wp_update_post to add tags separated by commas as in the code

```
//Create the post array
$post = array(
'ID' => 5,
'tags_input' => 'foo,bar,baz');     

// Update the post
wp_update_post($post);
```

the code works fine in my function.php theme, however I want to start a function to be running only in the post or in the edition creating a new post using `add_filter ('wp_update_post','');` or `save_post('wp_update_post,'');`

I tried to do this

```
function add_tags($post) {
    global $post;
    $idpost = $post->ID;
    $tags = 'tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4';

    $post = array(
    'ID' => $idpost,
    'tags_input' => $tags);     

    wp_update_post($post);

    return $post;
}
add_filter( 'wp_update_post', 'add_tags');
save_post( 'wp_update_post', 'add_tags');
```

put and not run into an infinite loop between

what can I be doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

solved:

```
function my_function(){
    if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ){

        // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
        remove_action('save_post', 'my_function');

        // update the post, which calls save_post again
        $post = array(
                'ID' => 5,
                'tags_input' => 'foo,bar,baz');  
        wp_update_post( $post );

        // re-hook this function
        add_action('save_post', 'my_function');
    }
}
// hook the function
add_action('save_post', 'my_function');
```